# How do I get the IP address of the server a request is coming from?

Tags: perl, client

How do I get the IP address of the server a request is coming from. Here's a scenario;

I have two servers - client|server. How can I detect the IP of the client server in perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `getpeername`. Please look up your perldoc.